# After my completion handler completes still unable to re-load tableView data swift 4

Tags: swift

In my model i've got a function to read in data from firebase.
I call completionHandler(true) when that's done. 
This is my viewDidLoad function in my controller that extends UITableViewController.

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let activityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
        tableView.backgroundView = activityIndicatorView
        self.activityIndicatorView = activityIndicatorView
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        model.readInFirebaseData { (success) in

            print("data read in")
            activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            dataArray = model.firebaseDataArray 
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    }
```

But the table remains empty and for whatever reason self.tableView.reloadData() isn't populating the table as i'd like but if I segue from the TableViewController and come back the list is populated.

I can't see exactly where i'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Update:

---

I still couldn't get it working so instead of a completionHandler i used a delegate. What i did was:

Singleton:

```
protocol Refresh{
     func refreshData()

    }

    var delegate:Refresh?


func readInFirebaseData()
{

    self.ref.child("users").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        user.name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
        self.dict.updateValue(user, forKey: uid)

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.delegate?.refreshData()
            print("main thread dispatch")

        }

    })    

}
```

The TableViewController:

```
class ListController: TableViewController, Refresh{

 viewDidLoad()
{
   model.delegate = self
}

 func refreshData() {
        print("called")
       array = model.array
       self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

That all works. The only issue really that I don't know the answer to is the DispatchQueue.main.async is getting called everytime firebase reads in a "user". But I put it at the end of the readInFirebase function and nothing was populated on the list. But in any case it works at the moment.

Comment: Can you show the code where you setup your tableview?

Comment: Hey @Wez. I'm extending a UITableViewController so the class is defined as class ListController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating.

Comment: And where are your UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `readInFirebaseData` method is asynchronous and the callback runs on a thread different from the main one.

Remember that all the UIKit related calls **must** be run on the main thread.

Try with:

```
model.readInFirebaseData { (success) in
    print("data read in")
    dataArray = model.firebaseDataArray 

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set delegate and dataSource:

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

And make sure you call `reloadData()` from Main Thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Calling it from background threads would typically not lead to your table reloaded, since this operation is UI-related. Any UI related operations should be performed from main thread.